# What do the terms CC, LD and SHIPPED refer to during the Kernel Source compilation process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What do the terms **CC**, **LD** and **SHIPPED** refer to during the Kernel Source compilation process?

Am I correct to assume that **[M]** indicates that it is being compiled as a module?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697800/gcc-compile-codes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CC** means that the file listed is being compiled from C by the C compiler. **LD** means that the file listed is being linked from a number of object files by the linker (`ld`); in this case, `aacraid` is built from [a number of files including `src.o`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/aacraid/Makefile). **SHIPPED** means that the file listed was shipped in the kernel source and is being copied as-is rather than rebuilt; it can be rebuilt if you really want to but doing that may require extra work (*e.g.* cross-compilation toolchains for firmware).

As you surmised, **[M]** means that the process is building a kernel module.

Comment: hi, is there a reason why on kernel build (simple 'make') is also build kernel modules [M] (isn't it supposed to build modules only with 'make modules') ? Thanks, ranran

Comment: @ransh the default build (`make`) builds the kernel and its modules. Run `make help` to see the details: `make` and `make all` are synonymous and build all the targets flagged with a `*`, currently `vmlinux`, `modules` and `bzImage`.